# reducing space taken by big math equation

Tags: fonts, math-mode, formatting

i hve few big equation in my file and they take lot of space. plase help me in reducing their size.i have already tried using \declaremathsizes but it only reduces math font size nt the space it takes.example is given here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,headings=normal]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\DeclareMathSizes{12}{1}{1}{1}
\begin{document}
this is the problem equation..
\begin{equation}
P^{bb}_{g}(n,p)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $n=0$}.\\
0, & \text{if $n=1$}.\\
p*P^{bb}_{g}(n-1,p)+\\
(1-p)^2+p*(1-p) \\
*P^{bb}_{g}(n-2,p) , & \text{if $n \geq 2$}.\nonumber
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

i have many like this and it eats lot of space.

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need to use low level commands like `\DeclareMathSizes` you could simply use `\small` or (since changing the font size here would look very strange) using a different layout where you use fewer lines (the first two choices in that case construction could be trivially combined which would save one line)

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,headings=normal]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\DeclareMathSizes{12}{1}{1}{1}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P^{bb}_{g}(n,p)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $n=0~\&~1$}.\\
p*P^{bb}_{g}(n-1,p) +(1-p)^2 &\\ 
{}+p*(1-p) *P^{bb}_{g}(n-2,p) , & \text{if $n \geq 2$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need a `{}` before the `+` so it gets binop spacing

Comment: easier, and perhaps more obvious, to use `equation*` rather than `\nonumber` to omit the equation number.  also, in the first line, that `2` should be `1`, since the last line explicitly includes the case where `n=2`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- you are absolutely right. Appreciated and Corrected accordingly.

Comment: solution saves 2 lines but when put in two column format text is running out of paragraph limit.

Comment: Hi, this is my test for two columns (4 lines), Just replace the cases environment with this new \begin{cases}
0, \hfill \text{if $n=0, 1$}.\\
p*P^{bb}_{g}(n-1,p) +(1-p)^2 \\ 
{}+p*(1-p) *P^{bb}_{g}(n-2,p),\\
\hfill \text{if $n \geq 2$}.
\end{cases}

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,headings=normal]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\DeclareMathSizes{12}{1}{1}{1}
\begin{document}
this is the problem equation..

If $n \geq 2$ then
\begin{multline*}
P^{bb}_{g}(n,p)=*P^{bb}_{g}(n-1,p)+{}\\
(1-p)^2+p*(1-p) 
*P^{bb}_{g}(n-2,p)
\end{multline*}
Otherwise $P^{bb}_{g}(n,p)=0$

i have many like this and it eats lot of space.



\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't it better to move the `+` down as well?

Comment: @daleif perhaps, it depends, an inline equation breaks after the operator, and as there is no alignment here I was thinking of it in those terms, but perhaps you're right.

Comment: I think that is what *Mathematics into type* usually recommends

Comment: did you happen to notice that this rendition takes four lines rather than three as accomplished by other suggestions?

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes well you could reword so the if and otherwise cases both come on the first line:-)